# Is it possible to create a work item from code editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, plugins, tfs, visual-studio-2013

We are working with TFS. Are there any plugins for Visual Studio 2012/2013 allow to create Work Items from code editor?

It's quiet annoying to get through several menus to create a work item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the menu bar shortcuts for this so can have quick access directly from the IDE:[image]

- Right click the menu bar area in Visual Studio and check `Work Item Tracking`

[image]

- [Customize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdee4yb6.aspx) the menus and toolbars to add shortcuts to your favorite work item types.

[image]